# Get severals class same name with JSOUP

Tags: java, html, class, jsoup

Is there a way to get HTML from severals class with same name with the plugin JSoup of Java ?

For example:

```
<div class="div_idalgo_content_result_date_match_local">
blablabla
</div>

<div class="div_idalgo_content_result_date_match_local">
123456789
</div>
```

I'd like get blablabla in one String and 123456789 in another.

I wish my question is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in several different ways.

If you want to select the div's with the class name above, you can simply use the following:

```
    Elements div = doc.select("div.div_idalgo_content_result_date_match_local");
```

This will give you a collection of `Element` that you can iterate over.
If you after that would like to select perhaps only the first one, you can use the `:eq(0)`-parameter, or the `first()`-parameter.

```
    Element firstDiv = div.first();
```

OR

```
    Elements div = doc.select("div.div_idalgo_content_result_date_match_local:eq(0)");
```

Note that the second method you are selecting from the document, while in the first method you select from the collection of `Element`'s. You can of course also change the value of the `:eq(0)` to something else that matches your element. There are many useful selectors that you can use that I have included a link to in the end of the answer.

The following code will split your div's into two:

```
    Elements div = doc.select("div.div_idalgo_content_result_date_match_local");
    Element firstDiv = div.first();
    Element secondDiv = div.get(1);

    System.out.println("This is the first div: " + firstDiv.text());
    System.out.println("This is the second div: " + secondDiv.text());
```

[JSoup Cookbook - Selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)